# how do you write json response destroy methods correctly in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, destroy

Here's the code for sending a json response associated with a working and non working status. Does anyone have recommendations for other resources?  This isn't working. Thank you.

```
if @content.destroy
  format.json { redirect_to @collection, status: :destroyed, notice 'Content was removed from collection.' }, :status => 200
else
  format.json { render json @content.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }, :status => 400
end
```

Comment: what framework/application are you using to communicate with your server?

Comment: i'm in rails and then using javascript to intercept via a backbone router or ajax

Comment: and why is that implementation not working for you? you cant catch exception in your ajax?

Comment: i believe something is incorrect with the syntax and i'd like to hear about any best practices

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR: if you are using some JS framework, then look up how that framework wants success and failure response to look like, if you are rolling your own - then do whatever makes more sense for you.

Long version:

There are couple ways you can return response from rails to your web app. Rails by default returns status code 2xx for success and 4xx for failed requests. Some web frameworks such as Extjs, like to [receive response with 200 code always and look at success key in the response to see if the request was successfult](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?47801-Database-Update-JSON-Response-Format). If you are writing your own JS that utilizes XHR, then you can do whatever you want: its up to you how you architect your API. I find it useful to return json response from server with 200 code and set success key to true or false so in my callback JS i can write something like:

```
if(request.data.success){
  successfulPost(response);
} else {
  failed(response);
}
```

one of the reasons I prefer that approach is that, if there is an exception, then I can actually distinguish from record not being saved due to validation errors as opposed to bug in code that caused exception. But that is a personal preference and some may argue that error is error and it does not matter what caused it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using Backbone.js in my project. I think I'm a bit confused with the syntax that goes into the response. Do you have any more resources? Thank you again.